# How does KD acronym unveils? /usr/include/linux/kd.h

Tags: files, source

I do understand that it is related to console (a "real" TTY which is at Ctrl+Alt+F[1-9]).

`ioctl_console` man page lists many KD* prefixed constants. there is also a `vt.h` in `/usr/include/linux` which is easy - a `VT` - virtual terminal or a pseudo-terminal. What a heck is KD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the `VT_` constants in `/usr/include/linux/vt.h` have, when possible, their high byte set to 0x56, which is the ASCII code for upper-case letter `V`.

At the beginning of `/usr/include/linux/kd.h`, there is a comment:

```
/* 0x4B is 'K', to avoid collision with termios and vt */
```

The `KD_`-prefixed two-byte `ioctl()` numbers all have their high byte set to 0x4b, which is literally the ASCII code value of the upper-case letter `K`.

So it's not primarily an acronym, but a mnemonic: when reading a hex dump, you can look at the character representation of the high byte of the ioctl value (or if you are a serious C programmer, you probably already know most of the ASCII table by heart anyway) to know that this is a "K series" ioctl, all of which deal with `K`eyboard and `D`isplay - in other words, the KVM-style system console on systems that have one.

So the primary reason for selecting `K` seems to be the fact that it corresponds with the high byte of the ioctl numbers, and the second letter is probably just picked to make it somehow meaningful - in this case, "Keyboard & Display" works.

(Some embedded systems and even large old-school Unix servers might not have a KVM-style console at all, but just a serial port that functions as a console.)

Comment: Keyboard Display.. i though Kernel Device :]